# Is Stack Overflow having a logout bug?

Tags: discussion, logout

Is Stack Overflow having a logout bug?

I recently noticed that one can log in to Stack Overflow through Google and is kept logged in even after one signs out of the Google.

Is this a bug or is this condition irrelevant? 
I would really appreciate if you could tell why is this so..

Comment: once you're logged into SO, google could vanish off the face of the planet and you'd STILL be logged into SO. However, if you quit out of SO, you'd no longer be able to log back in.

Comment: +1 Marc B, I always use it that way, I log in to google, then login to SO using Google then If I've nothing to do with google services eg. gmail etc, I log out of google and continue to use SO. In other words, when SO asks google whether you can enter into the door using google credentials google grants access! and doesn't wait at the door for you nor accompany you throughout your voyage in SO, I deduce :)

Comment: Thank u so much for ur response Marc, but then is login through google just an alternative to access SO ?

Comment: @user, [yes, it is](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/).

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OpenID log-out is a complete mess in general.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=openid%20logout) This is just one symptom of that.

Basically, to fully log out, you need to:

1. log out from your OpenID provider (here, Google, but the same applies [even if you log in through Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119399/improve-se-openid-logout-security-and-user-experience-on-shared-or-public-machine));
2. [clear your Stack Exchange global log-in credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout/global), and
3. finally, log out from each individual Stack Exchange site you've logged in to.

If you don't do all of these things, it's likely that valid log-in credentials will remain in your browser, making it trivial for anyone else using the same browser to log back in to your account.

One alternative solution is to always use [Private Browsing / Incognito mode](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Chrome) when logging in to Stack Exchange from a shared computer.  That way, any login credentials will automatically be cleared when you close the browser window.

Of course, this won't help if you've already logged in using a normal browser session, but in that case, you may be able to log yourself out by clearing all cookies and local storage from your browser.  (It's still best to manually log out from your OpenID provider and SE first, since that will also invalidate your credentials on the server, but clearing cookies and local storage is a good way to sweep out any login credentials you might have otherwise missed.)